# Auditing the licenses of libraries used in a Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm tasked to audit the licenses used in a project we are releasing, which is a Spring Boot multi-module Maven application.

The project is structured with a parent `pom.xml` declaring the Spring boot BOM:

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And then in one of the submodules (we have 4), which is the actual Web application, we have configured the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` with `repackage` task -- this creates a executable JAR of about 31 megabytes.

Running `mvn site` on a Spring boot project like this, then opening `target/site/index.html` and click on "Dependency management", we can see a very big list of dependencies provided by Spring Boot. Now, I'm fairly sure that we only use a one-digit quantity of this list (like 9 or 10 libraries), and I can read on the [spring-boot-maven-plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html) that this only concerns the "provided" scope, as Spring should be treated as a application container.

On the other hand, I'm using the `mvn dependency:analyze` and `mvn dependency:tree` goals to check the effectively used stuff, including transitive dependencies. Most of this stuff is not declared in the `pom.xml` files, as mentioned we have a parent pom that uses the BOM from Spring-boot and then in the single modules we activate dependencies as needed.

My questions:

1) On the legal side, can I assume that all the stuff shown by `mvn site` for Spring Boot is not the actual list of dependencies used at compile time? Would it be possible to force out of the JAR anything that we are not using? I tried to configure the spring-boot-manven-plugin by using an exclusion list, but the JAR size did not change.

2) how do I programmatically compile a list of dependencies and the attached licenses? I have the feeling that `mvn dependency:analyze` is the right path but is there a way to poll the License used by any module listed?

Comment: Just generate the JAR and see what libraries end up there... I'm sure you'll recognize most of them as very common open-source. That said, what kind of issue legal could have with Spring Boot? All dependencies it uses are coming with very permissible licenses. Or are you just compiling a list for paperwork purposes?

Comment: I suppose the reason is that companies are scared when they see the term "GPL".In any case you are right, Spring boot BOM lists Apache v2, MIT, LGPL and BSD licenses mostly. But what of components which declare "CDDL + GPL license" (e.g. Jersey) or "CDDL + GPLv2 with classpath exception"? there are also many of these strange and dual licensed components.

Comment: As I said, check what ends up in the packaged JAR (under `BOOT-INF\lib`).  Since that JAR is the only distributive artifact, that's all the legal would care about. I've built quite a number of Spring Boot apps, none of them had any GPL dependencies included, Jersey or anything else. My guess is that as long as you stay relatively "vanilla" WRT Spring Boot, you won't end up with any toxic dependencies whatsoever

Comment: Thanks, will keep this in mind.